# Cosa sono gli "apendizii"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La chimera*,  di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto queste parole pronunciate da un prete del Seicento:

> «Io, Dio solo in tre Persone, vi domando: che fine hanno fatto, in questi anni, le decime che mi erano dovute? E gli **apendizii**, e i donatici, legati per tradizione a tutte le feste del calendario liturgico, e ai nomi dei miei santi Martiri, chi me li ha sottratti? E il diritto di macinare, e di trarre acqua, e di avere tante carre di legna ad ogni inverno, che stanno scritti negli atti dei notai, quali piedi sacrileghi li hanno calpestati?».

Non so cosa sono questi "apendizii": non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visto che si parla di decime e donatici (in pratica, tasse e balzelli), direi che "apendizii" è una grafia leggermente diversa di "appendizi" o "appendizie".

Riporto qui la definizione di http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=appendizie

> appendizi n.m. pl. (dir.) prestazioni accessorie gratuite o regalie in
>   prodotti agricoli dovute usualmente dall’affittuario o dal mezzadro al
>   proprietario del terreno

Deriva dalla radice "appendice" che significa "parte aggiunta", nel senso appunto che si tratta di prestazioni aggiuntive rispetto a quanto già dovuto.